# Is there a way to add ellipsis to a textview based on location of another textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a `RelativeLayout` that has two `TextViews` in it that are created, programmatically, from random data.   One is left justified on a single line, the other is right justified on the same line.    When the data in TV1 is too long and reaches the left edge of TV2, they currently overlap each other.  I would like a gap between them, TV1 truncated and ... added to the end of TV1.

I know I can add `setEllipsize` and so forth to TV1... but from my experience with it, it works when the end of the PARENT is reached, not other `TextViews`.

Setting a physical character count is an option as is manually truncating/add ellipses is another option but then I have to watch for different size display widths being used, etc.    Plus, it is all based on how "wide" the TV2 ends up being too when displayed.

Is there a way to do this, programmatically, so the `TextViews` don't run over each other?

Here is what I have for them currently...  "RL" is my `RelativeLayout`.

TV1 has...

```
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        tv1.setId(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tv1.setTextSize(20);
        tv1.setText(myTV1Data);
        rl.addView(tv1, tvp1);
```

TV2 has...

```
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        tv2.setId(R.id.tv2);
        tv2.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tv2.setText(myTV2Data);
        tv2.setTextSize(20);
        rl.addView(tv2, tvp2);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Rules between 2 TextViews.

Here's the code:

```
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    tv2.setId(R.id.tv2);
    tv2.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tv2.setText(myTV2Data);
    tv2.setTextSize(20);
    rl.addView(tv2, tvp2);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    tvp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, tv2.getId());
    tv1.setId(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tv1.setTextSize(20);
    tv1.setText(myTV1Data);
    rl.addView(tv1, tvp1);
```

Comment: That worked... never thought of that!   Just for others that may be using this for reference... needed to add to `tv1.setSingleLine()` and `tv1.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END)`.